# How do I reorder a stacked bar chart in ggplot2 by the value of one portion of the stack?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

As the title says, I have a stacked bar chart which I want to arrange by the value of one of the types in the stack. I have seen questions asked/answered about ordering stacked bars in the way of which type is on the bottom/middle/top of the stack, but not the way I'd like.

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

##Create reproduceable dataframe
data<-tribble(
  ~Id, ~Type, ~Percent,
  "a", "one", "55",
  "a", "two", "15",
  "a", "three", "30",
  "b", "one", "87",
  "b", "two", "10",
  "b", "three", "3",
  "c", "one", "62",
  "c", "two", "25",
  "c", "three", "13",
  "d", "one", "26",
  "d", "two", "54",
  "d", "three", "20"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(across(Percent, as.integer))
```

The plot comes out like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(fill=Type,y=Percent,x=Id))+
  geom_bar(position="stack",stat="identity")+
  theme_bw()
```

[Stacked Bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez0k2.png)
(Note: Image not inline for lack of reputation)

To be clear, I am not worried about the fact that the legend (and order of the stacks) go in the order "one, three, two". What I would like is to change the order such that b comes first (lowest value of type "two"), then a,c,d. I'd like to know how to change this for each type, so I can have the order be b,c,a,d and go by increasing value of type "three".

Edit: I stitched some images together in paint to show the result I am looking for:
[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zYtd.png)

Thanks
~Nysa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by the description of your desired result but I give it a try. One option to reorder your `Id` categories by increasing order of Percent for `Type="three"` you could use `reorder` or `fct_reorder`, a helper column where you set the values for other `Type` categories to zero and using `.fun=sum`. Doing so will reorder `Id` by the `Percent` value for just `Type="three"`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~Id, ~Type, ~Percent,
  "a", "one", "55",
  "a", "two", "15",
  "a", "three", "30",
  "b", "one", "87",
  "b", "two", "10",
  "b", "three", "3",
  "c", "one", "62",
  "c", "two", "25",
  "c", "three", "13",
  "d", "one", "26",
  "d", "two", "54",
  "d", "three", "20"
) %>%
  mutate(across(Percent, as.integer)) |>
  mutate(Id = fct_reorder(Id,
    ifelse(!Type %in% "three", 0, Percent),
    .fun = sum
  ))

ggplot(data, aes(fill = Type, y = Percent, x = Id)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the swift response! This does indeed solve my problem, though getting my head around the why is proving tricky. Here are my thoughts, are they correct?:
mutate(Id=fct_reorder(...) line is saying "make values in the Type column that are: 
not 'three' into 0, 
are 'three' into the corresponding percent value" 

I'm not familiar with %in%, why did you not just use ==?
What does .fun=sum do?

Comment: `fct_reorder`  reorders a factor by the values of a numeric column. In case of multiple values per factor level it uses the median value, i.e. the median value of "one", "two" and "three", whereas I switched to `.fun=sum`, i.e. I reorder based on the sum of the values. But as we only want to order by "three" is set the other values to zero, i.e. we are still computing the sum for all 3 types, but the result is now only the value for "three". Concering `==` vs `%in%`. The latter is more robust in case our column contains NAs. Check c(1, NA) == 1 vs c(1, NA) %in% 1.